# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.toLowerCase()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

The application is stopping when I type on the keyboard to search for videos. The NullPointerException error is shown on line 100 in the VideoFilesActivity.java file. How to solve this problem? Please help me.

[Click here to see Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIQse.png)

[Click here to see Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIQse.png)

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.video_menu,menu);
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search_video);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menuItem.getActionView();
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    String inputs = newText.toLowerCase();
    ArrayList<MediaFiles> mediaFiles = new ArrayList<>();
    for (MediaFiles media:videoFilesArrayList) {
        if (media.getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(inputs)) {
          mediaFiles.add(media);
        }
    }
    VideoFilesActivity.videoFilesAdapter.updateVideoFiles(mediaFiles);
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: your is not empty, it is not initialized

Comment: Does this answer your question?  [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/328193)

Answer (score 0):

Some of the array list(videoFilesArrayList) entries might be  null.